# Neovim: plugins installed but not working

Tags: neovim, plugin-vim-plug

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I installed Neovim using apt-get. I downloaded the plug.vim script & put it into the `autoload` folder in `~/.config/nvim`. I put the following in my `init.vim`:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow.git'
Plug 'https://github.com/davisdude/vim-love-docs.git'
Plug 'https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox.git'
call plug#end()
```

I did `:PlugInstall`. The plugins were installed & show OK in `:PlugStatus`. But they are not working. As in nothing's changed at all.

I am new to both Vim & Neovim. I tried googling for a solution but there is almost no information on Neovim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't activated the plug-ins. In the `rainbow` case you should add

```
let g:rainbow_active = 1
```

to your init file (Neovim's one is located in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`). In case of `gruvbox` you should add

```
colorscheme gruvbox
```

Usually it's done after the `plug#end()`.

As for `vim-love-docs`, the GitHub code only includes the code for **generating** the plugin. From the GitHub page:

> Vundle: Clone the repo and follow the instructions below to generate the documentation (or download from vim.org). Then activate it using `Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin`'. See `:h vundle` for more.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I am new to vim. Do I activate every plugin like rainbow or does every plugin have different methods of activation? If so, where is it displayed?

Comment: All color schemes are activated the same way: `colorscheme name`.

Other plug-ins have it's own method, and it's usually explained in the README or the docs. To consult the docs run `:help plug-in-name` (you can use Tab for autocompletion) after installation. Usually plug-ins that need to be enable expose a global variable that sets that status like: `let g:pluginname_enabled=1` (VimL doesn't have boolean primitives so 1 means true). Other plug-ins are activated by default so if you want to disabled them at start up you must do the oposite (set the variable to 0).

Comment: Thank you very much Tae. I really appreciate your help. You just got vim/neovim another user! ;)

Comment: I'm glad I could helped you :) Welcome aboard! And don't hesitate to ask questions: Vim has a steep learning curve. I have been using Vim for 5 years (and at least a year ago I switched to Neovim) and I'm always learning something new.

Answer (score 0):

From the [NeoVim FAQ](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ):

> **Can I use Lua-based Vim plugins (e.g. neocomplete)?**
>
> Not yet. The legacy Vim if_lua interface is not (yet) supported.

`vim-love-docs` is Lua-based, so that is likely why that plugin does not appear to be working. If something is failing in the loading of that plugin, it *may* affect the loading of subsequent plugins (don't quote me on that though; I'm not intimately familiary with the inner workings of the plugin system).

Additionally, there are various parts of `vim` that are [changed](https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html#nvim-features-changed), [not yet implemented](https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html#nvim-features-missing) or [removed](https://neovim.io/doc/user/vim_diff.html#nvim-features-removed). I did not examine the source of the plugins you are using, but if they utilize any of the features you may see undefined behavior as a result.

I would recommend uninstalling all of the plugins then reinstalling the two that are not Lua-based one at a time.

Comment: I removed the love-docs plugin from my init.vim and ran PlugClean. But again nothing happens:(

Comment: @NightMare As a note, the plugin is written in Lua, but only uses Lua to generate the plugin scripts, which are vimscript. See my edit to the accepted answer for how to use vim-love-docs with Vundle.